# preg_match_all pattern from one array, subject from another

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match-all

I have the following problem where I'm stuck for hours:
I have an array with my regex, where I want to match with the subject from another array.

Regex array:

```
Array
(
    [tax] => /^(\S+\w)/
    [net_amount] => /^((?:[1-9]\d+|\d).(?:[1-9]\d+|\d)(?:\,\d\d)?)$/
    [tax_amount] => /^((?:[1-9]\d+|\d).(?:[1-9]\d+|\d)(?:\,\d\d)?)$/
)
```

Subject array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10,00 % Steuer von
    [1] => 1.650,31
    [2] => 165,03
)
```

I don't know how to match these two.

I tried quite things, such as:

```
foreach($pattern_val as $pattern_k3 => $pattern_val3) {
    $preg_pattern = $pattern_val3;
    foreach($file_content_array[$search_key] as $file_key => $file_value) {
        $preg_value = $file_value;
    }
    preg_match_all($preg_pattern, $preg_value, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
}
```

With this, I get just the last $preg_value in $matches.
I also tried some other methods but none weren't successful.

Would appreciate any hint.
Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what result you actually want to create.

Comment: So should the `tax` key be used to validate the `0` key, the `net_amount` for the `1` key and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's [preg_replace_callback()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) accepts arrays for patterns and subjects and you don't need to return a replacement string if you don't want to, leaving you free to do whatever you want inside the callback function. Like appending to a result array you defined beforehand. For example:

```
$results = [];

preg_replace_callback($patterns, function ($matches) use (&$results) { 
    $results[] = $matches[1]; // match of the first capturing group
}, $subjects);
```

`$results` for your test data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10,00
    [1] => 1.650,31
    [2] => 165,03
)
```

Comment: In my case, your answer was the key to my success. thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear what you are actually trying to achieve, what result you want to create. But this might point you into the right direction:

```
<?php
$patterns = array_values([
    "tax" => '/^(\S+\w)/',
    "net_amount" => '/^((?:[1-9]\d+|\d).(?:[1-9]\d+|\d)(?:\,\d\d)?)$/',
    "tax_amount" => '/^((?:[1-9]\d+|\d).(?:[1-9]\d+|\d)(?:\,\d\d)?)$/',
]);
$subjects = array_values([
    0 => "10,00 % Steuer von",
    1 => "1.650,31",
    2 => "165,03",
]);
$result = [];
for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
    preg_match($patterns[$i], $subjects[$i], $matches);
    $result[] = $matches[1];
}
print_r($result);
```

That would be an alternative:

```
<?php
$data = array_combine(
    [
        0 => "10,00 % Steuer von",
        1 => "1.650,31",
        2 => "165,03",
    ],
    [
        "tax" => '/^(\S+\w)/',
        "net_amount" => '/^((?:[1-9]\d+|\d).(?:[1-9]\d+|\d)(?:\,\d\d)?)$/',
        "tax_amount" => '/^((?:[1-9]\d+|\d).(?:[1-9]\d+|\d)(?:\,\d\d)?)$/',
    ]
);
$result = [];
array_walk($data, function($pattern, $subject) use (&$result) {
    preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
    $result[] = $matches[1];    
});
print_r($result);
```

Both variants create the same output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10,00
    [1] => 1.650,31
    [2] => 165,03
)
```